# h2o.glm coefficients match up with R glm but predictions do not match up

Tags: r, glm, h2o

I am observing odd behavior when using the interactions argument within the h2o.glm function.  Specifically, while the coefficients match up with base R glm function, the predictions do not.  Given almost identical coefficients, I would expect almost identical predictions.  I've carefully run two versions of the glm in R and two versions with h2o to demonstrate this behavior below.  Why are the predictions from the h2o.glm model with interactions not matching up with the other glm predictions (despite having nearly identical coefficients)?

Here is code to reproduce this behavior along with comments noting where the predictions do not match up, but coefficients do.

```
# Load libraries and ingest data.
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
infile <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/itx2za2p63iez29/h2o_data2.csv?dl=1"
indf <- read.csv(infile, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
indf$dow_x_hour <- paste(indf$dow, indf$hour)
indf[] <- lapply(indf[], as.factor)
str(indf)
# RESULT OF str(indf)
# 'data.frame': 8100 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ y         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ dow       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Fri","Sat","Sun": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 ...
# $ hour      : Factor w/ 3 levels "6","7","8": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
# $ dow_x_hour: Factor w/ 9 levels "Fri 6","Fri 7",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 ...
hf <- as.h2o(indf)


## FIRST TRY R ----------------
# Fit glm with R using interactions.
r_glm1 <- glm(y ~ dow + hour + dow:hour,
              family = "binomial",
              data = indf)

# Fit glm with R using concatenated column.
r_glm2 <- glm(y ~ dow_x_hour,
              family = "binomial",
              data = indf)

# These two R models generate near-identical predictions.
# RESULT: 4.496403e-15
max(abs(predict(r_glm2, type = "response") - predict(r_glm1, type = "response")))


## NOW H2O ----------------
# Fit glm with h2o using interactions.
h2o_glm1 <- h2o.glm(2:3,
                    1,
                    hf,
                    solver = "IRLSM",
                    family = "binomial",
                    interactions = 2:3,
                    lambda_search = FALSE,
                    lambda = 0,
                    compute_p_values = TRUE)

# Fit glm with h2o using concatenated column.
h2o_glm2 <- h2o.glm(4,
                    1,
                    hf,
                    solver = "IRLSM",
                    family = "binomial",
                    lambda_search = FALSE,
                    lambda = 0,
                    compute_p_values = TRUE)

# These two H2O models do not generate the same predictions.
# RESULT: 0.06211734
max(abs(h2o.predict(h2o_glm1, hf)$p1 - h2o.predict(h2o_glm2, hf)$p1))


## COMPARE R VS H2O PREDICTIONS ----------------

# The R and h2o models using concatenated column produce near idential predictions.
# RESULT: 3.356773e-07
max(abs(predict(r_glm2, type = "response") - as.data.frame(h2o.predict(h2o_glm2, hf))$p1))

# The R and h2o models using interactions DO NOT produce near idential predictions.
# RESULT: 0.06211732
max(abs(predict(r_glm1, type = "response") - as.data.frame(h2o.predict(h2o_glm1, hf))$p1))


## COMPARE R VS H2O COEFFIICENTS ----------------

# The R and h2o models using interactions produce near idential coefficients 
# (we manually matched them up here).
# RESULT: 3.341192e-06
df_coef <- cbind(h2o_glm1@model$coefficients_table, r_coef = coef(r_glm1)[c(1,6,8,7,9,2:5)])
max(abs(df_coef$coefficients - df_coef$r_coef))
```

Comment: H2O.AI has replicated this issue and filed a bug.  Progress can be followed here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3790

Comment: As it is a bug, that is being fixed, I wonder if this question should be closed/deleted? Alternatively, you could self-answer when the bug fix is released? I'm not sure which is StackOverflow's preferred approach.

Comment: @DarrenCook Good points.  I'm planning on posting a self-answer  when the bug fix is released, but if anyone finds reference for more preferred approach happy to go another route.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that for `h2o.predict`, it can't correctly deal with the interaction between two factors.

### **Locate the Issue**

Here I can show you that the `h2o.predict` incorrectly labeled your interaction terms.

```
pred1 <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(h2o_glm1, hf))$p1
diff <- unname(predict(r_glm1, type = "link")) - log(pred1/(1-pred1))
```

`pred1` is the response prediction from your `h2o_glm1` and `diff` calculates the difference between **link prediction** of `r_glm1` and `h2o_glm1`. The link prediction is just the linear combination of your input data with coefficient.

After this we can create a table of the difference by `dow` and `hour`

```
tapply(diff, list(indf$dow, indf$hour), mean)
#               6           7           8
# Fri -0.01645868 -0.01580134 -0.01580118
# Sat -0.01580673  0.01580109 -0.14319379
# Sun -0.01580207 -0.53848173  0.68233048
tapply(diff, list(indf$dow, indf$hour), sd)
# all 0
```

The standard deviation are all 0 indicates the difference of prediction in each levels is constant. This can prove that the errors come from the grouping of `dow` and `hour`.

We can also look further to see how `h2o.predict` labels the interaction term.
Here I can create the correct coefficient matrix for `dow` and `hour`:

```
coef <- h2o_glm1@model$coefficients
coef_M <- matrix(c(0,0,0,
                   0,coef[2],coef[3],
                   0,coef[4],coef[5]),3,byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
# [1,]    0  0.00000000  0.00000000
# [2,]    0  0.01580116 -0.12739263
# [3,]    0 -0.66587428  0.01645634
```

Then subtract the difference from this matrix, we can find the coefficient used by `h2o.predict`:

```
- tapply(diff, list(indf$dow, indf$hour), mean) + coef_M
#              6           7             8
# Fri 0.01645868  0.01580134    0.01580118
# Sat 0.01580673  6.854821e-08  0.01580116
# Sun 0.01580207 -0.1273926    -0.66587414

coef[2:5]
# dow_hour.Sat_7 dow_hour.Sat_8 dow_hour.Sun_7 dow_hour.Sun_8 
#     0.01580116    -0.12739263    -0.66587428     0.01645634
```

Here I also listed the coefficient of interaction terms of `h2o_glm1`. You can see that all the values in the last table match with certain coefficients of the interaction terms but not the correct one. Therefore, the matching of the interaction of two factors is incorrect in `h2o.predict`

```
#          6       7        8
# Fri  Sun_8   Sat_7    Sat_7
# Sat  Sat_7       0    Sat_7
# Sun  Sat_7   Sat_8    Sun_7
```

### **Change to Numerical**

However, the `h2o.predict` can deal with interaction between a factor variable and a numerical variable or two numerical variables.

If we change `hour` from factor to numeric: `indf$hour = as.numeric(as.character(indf$hour))` and do the same modeling process. Then the difference between base R `glm` and `h2o.glm` is quite little:

```
indf2 <- indf
indf2$hour <- as.numeric(as.character(indf$hour))
r_glm3 <- glm(y ~ dow + hour + dow:hour,
          family = "binomial",
          data = indf2)
hf2 <- as.h2o(indf2)
h2o_glm3 <- h2o.glm(2:3,
                    1,
                    hf2,
                    solver = "IRLSM",
                    family = "binomial",
                    interactions = 2:3,
                    lambda_search = FALSE,
                    lambda = 0,
                    compute_p_values = TRUE)
max(abs(predict(r_glm3, type = "response") - as.data.frame(h2o.predict(h2o_glm3, hf2))$p1))
# 9.866078e-08
```

### **Create Interaction Term**

I believe the best alternative solution, as you also stated in your question, is to create a new interaction variable. Here is another alternative solution, using `h2o.interaction` to generate this term:

```
hf3 <- hf
hf3$dow_hour <- h2o.interaction(hf,factors = 2:3, pairwise = TRUE, max_factors = 100, min_occurrence = 1)

h2o_glm4 <- h2o.glm(5,
                    1,
                    hf3,
                    solver = "IRLSM",
                    family = "binomial",
                    lambda_search = FALSE,
                    lambda = 0,
                    compute_p_values = TRUE)
max(abs(predict(r_glm1, type = "response") - as.data.frame(h2o.predict(h2o_glm4, hf3))$p1))
# 3.356773e-07
```